# About the hexadecimal result of a-b, where each is a pointer to an array

Tags: c, hex

I'm thinking about how the result of the following snippet is `0xc`? Shouldn't it be `c0-90=30`? I run it on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/rjsY0b).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int a[10] = {0};
    int b[10] = {0};
    printf("sizeof(a) = %d\n", (int)sizeof(a));
    printf("%p, %p\n", (void *)(a+10), (void *)(b+10));
    printf("a = %p; b = %p\n", (void *)a, (void *)b);
    printf("a-b = %p", (void *)(a-b));

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
sizeof(a) = 40
0x7ffcabb73ce8, 0x7ffcabb73cb8
a = 0x7ffcabb73cc0; b = 0x7ffcabb73c90
a-b = 0xc
```

Comment: It's clear from that output that `a+10` is the address of the tenth `int` after`a[0]`, which is 40 more than `a`. Unsurprisingly, `(a + 10) - a` is 10. Consider what that means for `b - a`(which is technically undefined behaviour, by the way).

Comment: @rici: I thought that would be `-(result)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you subtract pointers you get the difference in **locations** not difference in bytes

So, you get `0x7ffcabb73cc0` - `0x7ffcabb73c90` = `0x30` bytes

Dividing this by 4 bytes per integer, you get `0x0c` **integers**

Comment: `0x0c` = `12`(decimal) so the compiler adds 2-integer distance between the start of `a` and the end of `b` right?

Comment: @ptr_user7813604 - That is dependent on the compiler and/or memory and is not a requirement of the C language.